# How to unlink work account from OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

My employer implemented Office 365, with oneDrive.
I connected from home to transfer some work documents I was working on.
Then my work switched off oneDrive, so I can no longer log in from home. Win 10 says my 'Administrator is working on it'
How can I un-link this account in Win 10. ?
My employer is not very helpful, and wants me to bring my PC into work for them to 'work on it'. 
Understandably, I do not want this.
Any tips please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few steps:

**First**: Look for the OneDrive icon (blue or white clouds) at the right side of the taskbar (note: it can be in the hidden icons) then right-click the OneDrive icon
**Second**: click in the "Settings" option and the "Microsoft OneDrive" window should appear
**Third**: Select the "Account" tab and there click on the "Unlink this PC"

As a cleanup procedure you can also search for the "Credential Manager" in the Control Panel and remove all the Windows Generic credentials related to Office. This step is risk-free as far as you remember your Office 365 password

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This still produces a problem where Win10 says that I can't do that action, as my 'I.T.' department are not allowing it. However, they say that they are doing nothing.
I haven't tried the Credentials part yet, as I am not near my Home PC at the moment. Will try later

Comment: Interesting, I’ll take a look again, thanks.

The strange thing is indeed you're on your personal PC, so there should not be that much IT to deal with regarding local PC configuration.

I would uninstall OneDrive and then reinstall from the Office 365 if needed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive blocks Shell folders even after uninstall, so you need to install it again to easily unlink your device from OneDrive.

1. If you have already removed OneDrive from your PC, [download the package from Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/download) (**not from Microsoft Store**, these applications are different) and install it again.
2. After install click "**Unlink this PC**" in **Settings**, that's it.